# Как изменять public float число с помощью slider'а?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как изменять public float число с помощью slider'а?

```
//Чуствительность 
public float sensivity = 2f;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: Как то не очень и получилось

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour{

    public Slider slider;
    public float sensivity = 2f;

    public void SetSensivity(){
        sensivity = slider.value;
    }
}
```

потом в инспекторе slider'а пролистываете вниз и нажимаете на плюс под надписью on Value Changed переносите туда обьект на котором висит скрипт, в выпадающем списке находите свой скрипт и выбираете метод SetSensivity()